# Control.Anchor property groupbox

Tags: c#

I have two groupboxs which contain various textboxes and buttons, what a I want to do is to resize everything as equal as possible if the user drags the form from the left or from the right. What I was able to do is to resize just one of them, I can't do for all. 
Thank you guys.

Comment: Can you show us some code example of what have you tried?

Comment: Is this Winforms or WPF ? What code do you have ?

Comment: That is pretty normal, Anchor stops being useful quickly when the layout becomes convoluted.  TableLayoutPanel is your next best bet.

Comment: Acutally I'm not changing the anchor by code but only using the properties menu, I reallyd don't know what to show in this specific case

Comment: The designer generates code from that properties menu, it's found in (FormName).designer.cs file.  All the stuff related to a single groupbox will be collected in a few lines.  But just use a TableLayoutPanel like Hans suggested, Anchor alone will not accomplish proportional changes.

Comment: @HansPassant TableLayoutPanel is not working as I expected, it doesn't resize at all the controls when the program is running, it only does when it is not.

Comment: Dock fill your two GroupBoxes into the two cells that you created in your TableLayoutPanel.  Those two cells should be set for 50% Size Type.

Comment: Thanks to @LarsTech that illuminated me by saying to put the 2 groupboxes into TableLayoutPanel, by doing that plus using the anchor property I managed to do what I wanted, thank you guys for the answers.

Comment: For just two controls you can also use a (fixed) SplitPanel.